# Symfony Twig exception

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to use a HTML table bundle:

https://github.com/ekyna/TableBundle

Here is the calling code:

```
$table = $this->get('table.factory')->createBuilder(
          new InventoryType(), 
          ['name' => 'project_inventory_list']
        )->getTable($request);

        $content = ['content_area' => $table->createView()];

        return $this->render('MyProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $content);
```

I am getting an exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Ekyna\Component\Table\TableView could not be converted to string") in
>   MyProjectBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 6.

Stepped through code not sure whats going on - hoping it's a trivial issue???

| EDIT

```
{% extends 'mYThemeBundle:layout:base-layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}HEADER{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    {{ content_area }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What about you template snippet?

Comment: In the example which you shared brands used in twig `{{ ekyna_table_render(brands) }}` with that how  about yours ? could you share your twig also ?

Comment: I will add the template code to original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TWIG template, you have to do the following:

```
{% extends 'mYThemeBundle:layout:base-layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}HEADER{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
     {{ ekyna_table_render(content_area ) }}
{% endblock %}
```

You need to use the TWIG function `ekyna_table_render` to render the table view.

Comment: That solved that problem - now I am getting:

Unknown "bootstrap_set_style" function in EkynaTableBundle::table.html.twig at line 23.

I assume I am missing some bootstrap bundle dependency???

Comment: Probably yes, I think you have to install: `"braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle"`

Comment: Figured that out - now another dependency issue with intl - solved that - now another issue:

ClassNotFoundException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3624:
Attempted to load class "Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?

Answer (score 0):

After installing EkynaBundle (documentation was not up to date) I also needed to adjust the template as demonstrated above in addition to:

1. Install and enable WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle
2. Install and enable BraincraftedBootstrapBundle
3. Install twig extensions
4. Install and enable LiipImagineBundle

Thanks for all the help.